# Failing To Load Script File in WPF via FileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, fileopendialog

I am developing a WPF app and I just came across Loading a Script File(.xml) operation where I should load it from the system, get the file from the combobox and call Load Method.

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="ScriptCombo" SelectedIndex="0" >
         <ComboBoxItem Content="Select Aardvark Script" />
         <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding ScriptPath}" />
</ComboBox>

<Button Content="..." Command="{Binding Path=ScriptPathCommand}" Name="ScriptFileDialog" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private string _ScriptPath;
public string ScriptPath
{
    get { return _ScriptPath; }
    set
    {
        _ScriptPath = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ScriptPath");
    }
}

// Method gets called when ... Button is clicked
private void ExecuteScriptFileDialog()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { InitialDirectory = _defaultPath };
    dialog.DefaultExt = ".xml";
    dialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    ScriptPath = dialog.FileName; //Stores the FileName in ScriptPath
}
```

This opens a File dialog and lets me select a .xml file. Here it doesnt show me the CurrentWorkingDirectory when Dialog opens. How can that be achieved??? Thus After Selecting when I click Open and put a breakpoint near ScriptPath statemnt, it shows the path of the file in my combobox.

Also I want to get this file and store it in a FILE type and thus call LoadFile method. I did it in C++ as follows:

```
File file = m_selectScript->getCurrentFile(); //m_selectScript is combobox name
if(file.exists())
{
LoadAardvarkScript(file);
}

void LoadAardvarkScript(File file)
{
}
```

In WPf i did like :

```
ScriptPath = dialog.FileName;
if (File.Exists(ScriptPath))
{
   LoadAardvarkScript(ScriptPath);
}
}

public void LoadAardvarkScript(string ScriptPath)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Start Reading File");
}
```

I am passing FILE as perameter in C++ code and here I am passing a string. Will it create any issue while reading the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what your problem is, but the directory that is initially shown by an OpenFileDialog is set by its `InitialDirectory` property and hence is what you have put into your `defaultPath` variable. This could for example be the value of the [System.Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) property.

For the second part of your question, there is a [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class in .Net.

Comment: Thanks :) My first issue is cleared. For second issue, kindly check my updated code. Is it right?

Comment: I can't tell since i don't know what `LoadAardvarkScript` is supposed to do. It is of course possible to open a file from its path and then process its XML content.

Comment: Basically `LoadAardvarkScript` method parses the XML file and extracts the tagnames stored in xml script. Well I will try it out now and see if the operation goes smooth or not :) I am marking this answer as correct and will upvote too :) If i face any issue ill drop a comment. Hope you will get in touch :)